# Trying to connect to Neo4j Desktop using py2neo and receiving ``ServiceUnavailable: Cannot connect to any known routers`" when I run a query

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I renamed the existing example database from `Movies RDBM` to `Movies` and changed the password to pwd.

```
from py2neo import Graph
db=Graph("neo4j://neo4j:pwd@localhost:7687", name="Movies" )
```

No errors for the above

```
db.run("MATCH (n:Movie) RETURN n").to_table()
```

The above fails with
`ServiceUnavailable: Cannot connect to any known routers`

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using WSL and Jupyter Notebooks but Neo4j was running in Windows so 127.0.0.1 was pointing to the WSL loopback and there was nothing there to receive the API calls

Comment: So how did you solve? Did you have to move code out of WSL2 or did you find a way to get Windows Neo4j Desktop to communicated with WSL2 code?

Comment: I pointed my python code to the IP of the host (the windows machine)